# Flutter save user to use across whole app

Tags: .net, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter so I don't know almost anything but I have an API which gives me a user. I then want to save the user in the app so that I can use it to display information. Right now I am trying to save it as a static property to a class but it isn't working. Am I doing something wrong? Please help?

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:market/models/offer.dart';

class User{
  String id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int age;
  bool isVerified;
  String email;
  String phoneNumber;
  String password;
  String description;
  List<Offer> offers;

  // Constructor
  User({required this.id, required this.firstName, required this.lastName,
        required this.age, required this.isVerified, required this.email,
        required this.phoneNumber, required this.password, required this.description,
        required this.offers});

  // Factory constructor to create a User instance from a JSON map
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<Offer> converted = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < json['offers'].length; i++){
      converted.add(Offer.fromJson(json['offers'][i]));
    }
    return User(
      id: json['id'] as String,
      firstName: json['firstName'] as String,
      lastName: json['lastName'] as String,
      age: json['age'] as int,
      isVerified: json['isVerified'] as bool,
      email: json['email'] as String,
      phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'] as String,
      password: json['password'] as String,
      description: json['description'] as String,
      offers: converted,

    );
  }

  // Method to convert User instance to a JSON map
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
      'age': age,
      'isVerified': isVerified,
      'email': email,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
      'password': password,
      'description': description,
      'offers': offers,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more information. This specific code only shows the DTO/Model class of User type. Nothing about saving it on another variable or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an UserService (singleton)

```
final class UserService {
  factory UserService() {
    return instance;
  }

  UserService._internal();

  static final UserService instance = UserService._internal();

  User? _user;

  User? get user => _user;

  void setUser(User user) {
    _user = user;
  }

  void clearUser() {
    _user = null;
  }
}
```

> Example Usage

```
void main() async {
  ///
  /// 1. Fetch user data from the server
  /// 2. Save user data to UserService(singleton class)
  /// 3. Use user data from UserService
  /// 4. Clear,Update etc. user data from UserService
  /// 5. DONT USE THESE METHODS IN main() METHOD
  /// I just used it for example
  ///
  ///
  /// 'AsyncSnapshot<User>.nothing()' it's just for example you must use your own api response
  ///
  ///
  final result = const AsyncSnapshot<User>.nothing().data!;

  ///
  ///  User data saved to UserService
  ///
  UserService.instance.setUser(result);

  ///
  ///
  /// You can use UserService everywhere in your app
  ///
  print(UserService.instance.user);
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't i use it in main?

Comment: The main() method is mostly used to boot and start the services required for your application to run, and the cleaner and more organized it is kept, the better.
Of course, you can do whatever you want in main(), but what I mean by using it is not to write your functions directly in main().
For example, do not write the function that will retrieve user information directly to main(), create an intermediate class for this and do these operations there.
Don't forget to use try-catch because any error in main will prevent your application from running.

Comment: Can is add a function that fetches a user and sets the logged user into the user service to this class

Comment: Yes of course you can

Comment: Sorry for bothering but now when i try to acces the userService.instance.user it doesnt let me it says "The property 'email' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'". Why does this happen

Comment: I kind of fixed it but at the start it throws some errors but then when i do a quick restart of the app it works fine.

Comment: My suggestions for you are:

1- Create the user model with Freezed (freezed package)
In this way, updating your model creates functions such as toJson, fromJson, copyWith for you.

2- When creating a model, I usually set most fields to nullable because it is necessary to be 100% sure. There is no guarantee that the data will be 100% correct and I take my precautions.